# C# NumSharp undefined behavior when using `object` parameter compared to explicit type parameter

Tags: c#, types, casting, numsharp

I am working with [NumSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NumSharp/) and a bit new to it. I would like to set multiple data values and there are two main functions of concern:

```
NDArray.SetValue(object value, param int[] indices)
NDArray.SetData(object value, param int[] indices)
```

The first one `SetValue` expects full index of a single value element, for example, if you have `np.zeros(3,3)` it expects full indexing, and if there is missing index it will use `0` in its place.

For example:

```
var arr = np.zeros(3,3);
arr.SetValue(10.0, 0); 
arr.SetValue(10.0, 0, 0);
```

Both lines are equivalent.

On the other hand, `SetData` will modify an entire sub-array based on the index, and if you give full index, it works like `SetValue`. For example:

```
arr.SetData(10.0, 0); // sets all arr[0] values to 10
arr.SetData(10.0, 0, 1); // sets arr[0][1] to 10
```

Now, for my use case, I would like to redefine a function that accepts multiple values and treats each one as a sub-array index.

```
arr.SetMultiData(10.0, 0, 1); /// sets arr[0] and arr[10] values to 10
```

Naturally, I went for an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetMultiData(this NDArray arr, object value, int[] indices)
    {
        foreach (var i in indices)
            arr.SetData(value, i);
    }
}
```

But here is what completely lost me. This code, which does not use extension method, works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NDArray arr = np.zeros(3, 3);
        int[] indices = new int[] { 0, 1 };
        double value = 10;

        foreach (var i in indices)
            arr.SetData(value, i); 

        Console.WriteLine(arr.ToString());
    }
```

Output:

> [[10, 10, 10],[10, 10, 10],[0, 0, 0]]

This code doesn't:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NDArray arr = np.zeros(3, 3);
        int[] indices = new int[] { 0, 1 };
        double value = 10;

        arr.SetMultiData(value, indices);

        Console.WriteLine(arr.ToString());
    }
```

Output:

> [[10, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]

This isn't always going to print, in most cases it just fails to print and I believe the underlying `arr` structure is corrupted accordingly, which leads to undefined behavior when I run it multiple times.

Now, the last bit. When I change the `Extension` method to accept `double` instead of `object`, it works perfectly. But I need the extension method to work with more than one type given it is just a wrapper around `SetData`. Given this, I also tried changing the method to be generic:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetMultiData<T>(this NDArray arr, object value, int[] indices)
    {
        T val = (T)value;
        foreach (var i in indices)
            arr.SetData(val, i);
    }
}
```

I was shocked when this didn't work and produced the same output. Basically, I made the explicit cast from object to type. And I called the function like this: `arr.SetMultiData<double>(value, indicies);` and I used the debugger and compared the code that worked with this and the types are exactly the same ones that are passed to `arr.SetValue` given `i = int` and `val = double`, yet one works and one doesn't.

What causes such behavior? And why does it work when I explicitly set it to `double` when it fails both using generic/`object` types?

For reference, here is the [`SetData` implementation.](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp/blob/476113f8b9e13e4ad6fe5e04fd4671af44c5a889/src/NumSharp.Core/Backends/Unmanaged/UnmanagedStorage.Setters.cs#L184) which is open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `double` is implicitly convertible to `NDArray` (by implicit operator defined in `NDArray`). So when you do:

```
arr.SetData(value, i);
```

and `value` is of type `double` - the overload being called is `SetData(NDArray, int[)`, because it's the best fit given that `double` is convertible to `NDArray`.

However when `value` is of type `object` or even of unresolved generic type (`T`) - then overload being called is `SetData(object, int[])`, so things go wild (because those overloads do quite different things IF value you pass as object is not NDArray, and it's not - it is double). Overload is chosen at compile time, and there is no way compiler can choose the `NDArray` overload even in generic case (since overload chosen should fit for any possible generic types you can pass).

In your case you can "solve" this by using `NDArray value` in your extension method instead of object or generic:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetMultiData(this NDArray arr, NDArray value, int[] indices)
    {
        foreach (var i in indices)
            arr.SetData(value, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be damned, this actually worked. You're godsent. Now I get it, and I get why the generic type doesn't work either. My problem with the generic type is I was thinking of C++'s implementation of generics where the actual thing is resolved on compilation time and hence the proper function will be called, that is not the case with C# generics, therefore, the `SetData` in the extension method still links to `SetData(object ...)` instead of `SetData(NDArray...)`